# 24VAC to 12VDC momentary switch short

Tags: relay, converter

I'd like to hook up a wireless bell to my garage door control board (bell should ring when door is opening).

The garage door control board does expose several contacts dedicated to lighting indicators, that are to my understanding all AC.

- 230V (25W max) blinking while opening
- 230V (60W max) constant while opening
- 24V (3W max)  constant while opened

I chose a pretty basic [Wireless bell](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00M8AQN56).

My idea was somehow to short the momentary switch of the remote (that rings the bell when pressed) when there is AC current from some of theses pins.

- What would be the cheapest and most cost effective way to do that?
- Do I need a AC/DC converter or is there some kind of cheap low-power relay that could do the trick?

---

EDIT: Here is the actual notice of the garage door control board: [PDF link](http://www.peiter.pl/allegro/download/Came/came_zm3e_instr.pdf), go to page 6 for lighting options.

Thanks!

Comment: You may not need anything if the controller board contacts do not supply power.

Comment: How could I be sure of that? Would a multimeter be enough to test this?

Comment: Post the data you have on it, plus sharp well-lit photos of the back and front of the board if you have little data.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this board actually supplies power to the outputs, so you will need to connect something there to convert to a contact closure.

A conservative suggestion would be to source a 240VAC-input interval timer module which would give you a timed contact closure (followed by a drop out) whenever power is applied. Just set the timer to a second or two to simulate a button press.

You could probably just slap a 240VAC-input relay on the flashing output, but it's possible the controller would not like the inductive load and you'd have to attach a snubber or MOV.